# simplexml_load_file() error in php

Tags: php, xml

I have created a test xml whose content is in gujrati using php

```
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$fieldvalue = mb_convert_encoding($question['questiontext'],'ISO-8859-1','UTF-8');
$value2 = $doc->createTextNode($fieldvalue);
```

XML file is created successfully but when i try  to use simplexml_load_file function to render the XML content i get the following errors:

> Warning: `simplexml_load_file()` [function.simplexml-load-file]: testsxml/test27_4.xml:2: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xC9 0xD6 0xF7 0x20

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced the same problem, and it was solved by using [utf8encode](http://php.net/utf8encode). I see you have use the multi byte version, but trying this might be worth a shot. Also make sure you are not encoding things twice.

One more thing. I suppose DomDocument does it for you, but check that & is &amp; and so on.